# The compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the Tychonoff topology on the set $Y^X$ of continuous functions from
$X$ to $Y$ , i.e., the subspace topology as a subspace of the space of all functions
$X\to Y$ with the product topology. Which parts, if any of the below Theorem hold
in this topology? Give either proofs or counterexamples.

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff and $Y$ and $T$ arbitrary
>   Hausdorff spaces. Given a function $f : X \times T \to Y$, define, for each $t\in T$, a function $f_t:X\to Y$ by $f_t(x)=f(x,t)$. Then $f$ is continuous if both of the following
>   conditions hold:
>   (a) each $f_t$ is continuous; and
>   (b) the function $T\to Y^X$ taking $t$ to $f_t$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this directly answers your question but it sounds relevant to finding monoidal closed structures on the category of topological spaces. This question was studied, but without that language,  in my paper ["Function spaces and product topologies"](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/functionspaces.pdf), *Quart. J. Math.* (2) 15  (1964), 238-250 for Hausdorff spaces and the compact-open topology. In Remark 1.15 on p.242 it is stated that the exponential law is valid with the product topology on the space of continuous functions and for the  topology on $X \times Y$ which gives rise to separately continuous functions $X \times Y \to Z$.

These ideas are pursued for the non Hausdorff case in the following paper, available from the Journal's web site.

Booth, P.; Tillotson, J.
Monoidal closed, Cartesian closed and convenient categories of topological spaces. 
*Pacific J. Math.* 88 (1980), no. 1, 35–53.